# Spring Integration - Reading files from multiple locations & putting them at a central repository

Tags: spring-integration

I need to transfer the file contents from multiple servers to a central repository as soon as there is a change in the file. Also the requirement is that only the changed contents should be transferred, not the whole file.
Could someone let me know if it is possible using Spring-Integration File Inbound/Outbound Adapters.

Answer (score 0):

The file adapters only work on local files (but they can work if you can mount the remote filesystems).

The current file adapters do not support transferring parts of tiles, but we are working on [File Tailing Adapters](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration/pull/802) which should be in the code base soon. These will only work for text files, though (and only if you can mount the remote file system). For Windows (and other platforms that don't have a `tail` command, there's an Apache commons `Tailer` implementation but, again, it will only work for text files, and if you can mount the shares.

If you can't mount the remote files, or they are binary, there's no out of the box solution, but if you come up with a custom solution to transfer the data (e.g. google `tailing remote files`), its easy to then hook it into a Spring Integration flow to write the output.